# How to fix brew install pyside error?

Tags: python, pyside, iterm2

When i try to brew install pyside on iTerm, after it finishes I receive

```
/bin/sh: line 1: 19051 Segmentation fault: 11  /usr/local/Cellar/shiboken/1.1.2/bin/shiboken --generator-set=shiboken --enable-parent-ctor-heuristic --enable-pyside-extensions --enable-return-value-heuristic --use-isnull-as-nb_nonzero /tmp/pyside-s45Y/pyside-qt4.8+1.1.2/macbuild/PySide/pyside_global.h --include-paths=/tmp/pyside-s45Y/pyside-qt4.8+1.1.2/PySide:/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.5/Frameworks --typesystem-paths=/tmp/pyside-s45Y/pyside-qt4.8+1.1.2/PySide:/tmp/pyside-s45Y/pyside-qt4.8+1.1.2/PySide/QtCore --output-directory=/tmp/pyside-s45Y/pyside-qt4.8+1.1.2/macbuild/PySide/QtCore --license-file=/tmp/pyside-s45Y/pyside-qt4.8+1.1.2/PySide/QtCore/../licensecomment.txt /tmp/pyside-s45Y/pyside-qt4.8+1.1.2/macbuild/PySide/QtCore/typesystem_core.xml --api-version=4.8 --drop-type-entries=""
make[2]: *** [PySide/QtCore/PySide/QtCore/qabstracteventdispatcher_wrapper.cpp] Error 139
make[1]: *** [PySide/QtCore/CMakeFiles/QtCore.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Yep, I have exactly the same issue, and no idea what's causing it. But I have had problems related to **shiboken** every time I've tried to get anything going with PySide.

Comment: Hello from Homebrew! I try to update our pyside.rb to 1.2.0 and I get another error, but also in qabstracteventdispatcher_wrapper.cpp. I assume there is something borked with shiboken/pyside with the current qt/cmake version. I was not yet able to fix this ... :-(